# WordPress table_prefix without "underscore"

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to insert some date into WordPress database using the following code:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "liveshoutbox";
$wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(...
```

This worked well...

**But I found that this does not work if table prefix does not contain underscore "_" in wp-config.php.**

I open "`wp-config.php`" and found that "`$table_prefix`" is set to '`www`' (without underline."

I tried to change the prefix (after installation) but could not.

In this case, how can I resolve the issue?

Thanks for your help.

Added:
Table names in phyMyadmin:
[image]

Comment: are you trying to change table prefix on wp-config.php after installation ?

Comment: after installation could not change the prefix.....

Comment: Could you var_dump($table_name) to see what is actually output and give an example of what other tables are named.

Comment: @Ajith. After installation, I tried to change the prefix using a plugin which changed the prefix actually. But some elements such as sliders did not work after changing the prefix. So I had to revert it back to original one.

Comment: @Sarcoma. I included the screenshot showing the table names in phyMyAdmin. Could you please let me know how I can  check "var_dump($table_name)"? Thanks.

Comment: Just paste it in, and post back what it prints out  when you out load the page. var_dump manual page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: "But I found that this does not work if table prefix does not contain underscore "_" in wp-config.php." I can't see why that would cause a problem. There's nothing special about an underscore in a table name. Are you really sure that's the cause of the problem? What does "does not work" look like? [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs) even gives examples of prefixes without underscores, so I'd assume they should work just fine.

Comment: (Also, you're attempting to insert into `wwwliveshoutbox`, but it doesn't appear in your list of tables. Are you sure you created your table properly?)

Comment: @ Matt. Sorry. The table name above is an example only.

Comment: So you haven't actually posted the code that's causing you a problem?

Comment: @Sarcoma. The output is as follows: string(20) "liveshoutbox"

Comment: Looks like the prefix is missing. It should have said "wwwliveshoutbox"

Comment: @Sarcoma. Thanks. $tableprex = $wpdb->prefix; var_dump($tableprex); It outputs "NULL". I think something wrong with the table prefix...

Comment: Where are you writing this code, exactly?

Comment: @Matt. Thanks for your comment. I try to send Contact Form message to a forum based plugin before sending email using "wpcf7_before_send_mail" action. NO problem with other sites... I think it's related to the web-hosting server setting or something wrong with WordPress installation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
$table_name = "wwwliveshoutbox";
```

The prefix just adds the stored prefix which would make the code more dynamic, but this should work.

Or you could try:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->base_prefix . "liveshoutbox";
```

Or this:

```
$table_name = $table_prefix . "liveshoutbox";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tested all three and I still could not resolve it. The problem is that "$wpdb->prefix" returns "NULL". I don't know if it's related to the missing underscore or not...

Comment: So what worked in the end? I'd be happy to clarify my answer, if it helped you it may help others.

Comment: I could not resolve this issue. I think it's specific to the webhosting server or php version or something else...

Answer (score 0):

first, open wp-config.php and change table_prefix ( on line 67 or around ) to

```
$table_prefix  = 'www';
```

Then use in your code

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "liveshoutbox";
```

Then i tshould work

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already set "table prefix" to "www". The problem is that "$wpdb->prefix" returns "NULL". I don't know the reason. If I add "require_once('../../wp-load.php');" by referring to https://wordpress.org/support/topic/need-help-accessing-wpdb?replies=4, it seems that the site could not load "wp-load.php" file.

Comment: can you replace wp-blog-header.php file from fresh wordpress and test

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I reinstalled WordPress from the Update section of Dashboard. I tested the same code for two different sites which run on the same webhosting server. It works without error in one site, but it does not on the other wordpress site...